# How to install Nvidia drivers on Dell Latitude laptop - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

After upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04.1, both 64 bit, I got stuck in an infinite login loop - every time I logged in on `lightdm`, after logging in the screen would go black and then come back to the login screen. Logging in on `tty0` worked fine. I have a Del Latitude 3350 laptop with a Core i5 5200U and an Nvidia GeForce 830M. The upgrade decided I needed the `nvidia-361` drivers, before I had been using `nvidia-352`. A lot of the instructions I came across early on mentioned Secure Boot in my UEFI BIOS, but that was already off (I can't remember if I switched it off as soon as I got the laptop or if it shipped that way from Dell). Re-installing and/or reconfiguring `lightdm` didn't help. They did at least point me in the direction of uninstalling the Nvidia drivers but that's only a partial solution. This is not a duplicate of other questions I've seen on askubuntu as the steps that worked for others didn't work for me. Possibly the closest guide is [How to install sane graphics drivers for Nvidia Optimus hardware on *Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792929/how-to-install-sane-graphics-drivers-for-nvidia-optimus-hardware-on-ubuntu-16-0). However, that doesn't make the Nvidia GPU usable for me, I had to install Bumblebee. Also, that guide links to [Bumblebee on a Lenovo T440p [NVidia GT 730M] with XUbuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS]{http://lenovolinux.blogspot.co.za/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html?m=1} except that following those instructions actually left me without a working Bumblebee too.

After much Googling I found that the partial solution was to uninstall the Nvidia drivers. I eventually found [these](http://nlug.ml1.co.uk/2016/02/an-almost-authoritative-guide-to-nvidia-prime-and-bumblebee/5065) instructions which got me to the point of being able to log in.

An important note before continuing, it seems you need to have the `intel-microcode` drivers installed using the Additional Drivers tab in System Settings. I already had them installed (probably from Ubuntu 15.10 days) so I never tested what happens if they're not installed.

I used the following commands to remove Bumblebee and the Nvidia drivers, followed by re-installing the Nvidia drivers. Note that you need to add the graphics drivers repository to get the latest Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge .*nvidia.* bumblebee.* .*primus.*
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
```

This resulted in the following packages being installed:

```
bbswitch-dkms libcuda1-367 libjansson4 nvidia-367 nvidia-opencl-icd-367 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings screen-resolution-extra
```

Then I did `rm .nvidia-settings-rc`.

At this point, the instructions say to run some programs that use the GPU. If I run `clinfo` (I do use the GPU for OpenCL development) then everything works fine. Other OpenCL programs also work fine. However, If I run `glxinfo` I get the following output:

```
name of display: :0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

I carried on with the instructions so I could get Bumblebee running. `sudo prime-select intel` was needed because otherwise, after rebooting, I get back to the infinite login loop. After rebooting, I did `sudo apt install bumblebee` followed by editing `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` to change all the instances of `nvidia-current` to `nvidia-367`. I also edited `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` to include the line `blacklist nvidia-367`. Since there's no `nvidia-367-updates` or `nvidia-experimental-367` packages for me to install, I did not blacklist them.

After rebooting, I can run `primusrun clinfo` and it prints out the Nvidia platform. Running OpenCL programs on the Nvidia GPU also works when using `primusrun`. However, `primusrun glxinfo` gives me an error:

```
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)
```

Using `optirun` for anything gives me a similar error, e.g. `optirun clinfo` and `optirun glxinfo` both give:

```
[  462.796690] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

[  462.796725] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I tried changing the line `Bridge=` to `Bridge=primus` and the line `PMMethod=auto` to `PMMethod=bbswitch` in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`. That didn't help.

How do I get Bumblebee and Nvidia's drivers working here, it seems no single set of instructions works? Bonus: How do I get Nvidia drivers working fully when using `prime-select nvidia` instead of Bumblebee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions I found so far gets Bumblebee working (mostly) and provides a means of manually switching off the Nvidia GPU when not in use. I haven't yet gotten `glxinfo` to work when using `prime-select nvidia` instead of `optirun`.

I started following [these](https://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.co.za/2016/04/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-on.html) instructions. I added `i915` and `bbswitch` to `/etc/modules`. I ran `sudo gpasswd -a $USER bumblebee` and `sudo systemctl enable bumblebeed`. Those two commands seem to have finished successfully. After rebooting, the problem remains the same. If I do `sudo prime-select nvidia` followed by `glxinfo` I still get the error `couldn't find RGB GLS visual or fbconfig`.

At this point I decided to install `bumblebee-nvidia` - the instructions I linked to in my question said don't, the link above did include it however. Surprisingly, this fixed my problems mostly. Now, doing `optirun glxinfo` or `primusrun glxinfo` prints out the Nvidia GPU's information. `optirun glxgears` and `optirun glxheads` (and also using `primusrun`) works fine. A word of caution, in a previous iteration through trying to fix this problem, installing `bumblebee-nvidia` broke `optirun`/`primusrun`.

The only thing that doesn't work is `prime-select nvidia` followed by `glxinfo`. Then I still get the error about failing to load module "mouse". Also, if I run `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` I keep on getting `0000:04:00.0 ON`, which I believe indicates my Nvidia GPU is still on. Running `lspci | grep NVIDIA` returns `04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 830M] (rev a2)` which confirms the PCIe address of my Nvidia GPU.

The power problem, based on `dmesg | grep bbswitch`, was that the `nvidia` module was preventing the GPU from switching off. Manually switching off the Nvidia GPU is possible by running `sudo rmmod nvidia_drm`, `sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm`, `sudo rmmod nvidia_modeset` and `sudo rmmod nvidia`, followed by `sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF`. Not great though so I went looking for an automatic method to make this work.

To sort out Bumblebee not switching off my Nvidia GPU, I tried the instructions [from the bumblebee project](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch) but without success. Specifically, my `/etc/modprobe.d/bbswitch.conf` contains `options bbswitch load_state=0` and I added `bbswitch load_state=0` to the end of `/etc/modules`. I did run `sudo update-initramfs -u`, followed by rebooting, but `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` still shows the GPU is ON. For the moment, I'm working around this by using a script with the `rmmod` commands to switch off the Nvidia GPU. Running any program with `optirun` or `primusrun` automatically reloads those drivers.