# NVIDIA GeForce GT525M with Optimus on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I have a Dell 15 l502x with NVIDIA GeForce GT525M with Optimus in it. I installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it but am unable to use the NVIDIA card. 2 observations:

1. All NVIDIA drivers installation fail, I have tried many versions. I saw this error: `W: Possible missing firmware for module i915`. It gets stuck in the login screen loop after reboot.
2. Settings show that the graphics card is 'Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits)'. When I do `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`, it throws this error:

   ```
   the following packages have unmet dependencies:
   xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-20
   Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

Background: I had Ubuntu 14.04 LTS before this where I tried installing ROS. I do remember it saying something like, some packages could destroy my Xserver. But, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 over 14.04 as fresh install, without updating. I apologize, I am a little new.

Comment: Open Additional Drivers, select the recommended Nvidia driver. Apply. Reboot.

Comment: Hi Michael Bay, thanks, but I have tried that. Nothing shows up as recommended. It is a list of different driver versions from Nvidia and some Xserver based. I have tried installing different versions of Nvidia drivers, both from GUI as well as from terminal. It enters into a login windows loop after that. So, then I go to TTY, purge nvidia drivers and am back to where I started.

Comment: Check here https://www.geforce.com/drivers what versions support the GT525M, *then* fully update your system, open Additional Drivers and choose accordingly. If it doesn't work you have other issues going on.

Comment: Yes, Michael I am thinking 2 problems: 1)My graphics card is based on Optimus which create a problem even if the graphics driver page says it is supported. 2)I am getting this error when I try to install drivers: W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915

Comment: Not an error, "W" stands for "warning" and it can be ignored. It has nothing to do with the Nvidia part anyway. PS: I'm aware of the hybrid graphics and it nothing to do with it. For managing and switching between Intel/Nvidia you need to install the Nvidia proprietary drivers and switch using the profile at Nvidia X Server Settings (reboot required).

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the prompt reply. I wish it worked the way you described, but it doesn`t, and I don`t know why. I ran into a lot of such questions and blogs like this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/792929/how-to-install-sane-graphics-drivers-for-nvidia-optimus-hardware-on-ubuntu-16-0?rq=1              This tells me that it is actually a problem many users face. I haven`t been able to get to the solution which works for me. I tried bumblebee too, didn`t work. It takes me to a login window loop too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:
1. Update package lists

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2. Remove nouveau

   sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
3. Install bumblebee, primus and NVidia Drivers

   sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-384
4. Blacklist NVidia Drivers in your /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf i.e add towards the end of file
   ' # 384
   blacklist nvidia-384
   blacklist nvidia-384-updates
   blacklist nvidia-experimental-384 '
5. Update bumblebee Config to Point to 384.x Drivers in /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
   ....Driver=nvidia
   ...
   LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-384:/usr/lib32/nvidia-384
   ...
   XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-384/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
   ...
6. Select Mesa as your GL Provider

   sudo update-alternatives --config i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
   Select /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf

   sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf
   Select /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/ld.so.conf

   sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
   Select /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
7. Reboot

   sudo reboot
8. Disable gpu-manager i.e Add nogpumanager to your /etc/default/grub file
   ...
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nogpumanager"
   ...
9. Update your grub menu

   sudo update-grub
10. Re-build the bbswitch and nvidia modules.

    sudo dpkg-reconfigure bbswitch-dkms
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-384
11. Reboot

    sudo reboot

Source: http://lenovolinux.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html?m=1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/762969)

Comment: Thanks @ravery I have updated the post now. Please let me know if this is fine now, or needs modification.